# how to display string with echo that has die function

Tags: php, echo, die

```
echo 'SKU is B001'.die();
```

in the above line due  to die at end, the echo not displays the string.

how die works here?

Comment: Do you want to know why it dies before outputting the string?

Comment: yes i want to know about , how  die() works here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of evaluation is as following:

```
echo('SKU is B001'.die());
```

PHP needs to evaluate the parameter for `echo` before it can call echo:

```
'SKU is B001'.die()
```

The `.` operator now needs to evaluate `'SKU is B001'`, which is just `'SKU is B001'` and the result of `die()` before it can concatenate the strings;

Once it calls `die`, the execution of the program stops.

Answer (score 1):

Use die function as `die('SKU is B001');`

Answer (score 1):

echo 'SKU is B001'.die("died");

"died" will be output.

i think the block `'SKU is B001'.die("died");` will be run before echo.